# php script works well on the localserver but does not work on the remote server

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I have an android app that needs registeration i have php code that works fine when i am using it on the local server however

it does not work on the remote server.

```
/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");

//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please Enter Both a Username and Password.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    //now lets update what :user should be
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username']
    );

    //Now let's make run the query:
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,email) VALUES ('$user','$password','$email') ";
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);

    //for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
    //header("Location: login.php"); 
    //die("Redirecting to login.php");


} else {
?>
    <h1>Register</h1> 
    <form action="register.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
    </form>
    <?php
}

?>
```

The insert part does not work on the remote server however it does work on the local server perfectly well. Please any help will be appreciated i think that the problem is in the  insert query so any help will be appreciated as i am new to php

Comment: What does your `$ex->getMessage()` produce? Have you put on error reporting -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Comment: Also, you should be binding that insert query....

Comment: Please post any relevant errors. Also, you have an SQL injection vulnerability in your insert command.

Comment: @Darren my problem is in the insert query all the other ones are working well

Comment: @Darren is pointing out that your first SQL command is selecting from the column named `1` from the `users` table (I don't think a column can be named 1), but is later trying to insert into columns `username,password,email`. The code is inconsistent.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara THE ERROR that it does not insert it is not an error but it catches an error therefore it shows my message which is Database Error 2. Please try again

Comment: If you are getting the "Database Error2. Please Try Again!" response, that means you are getting an exception in one of the lines of the lines inside the try statement. Could you uncomment the line containing `$ex->getMessage()` and give us the message?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaged do what **Alexander** just said please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you most likely are trying to run the query like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,email) VALUES ('$user','$password','$email') ";
```

When in fact you should be binding those user input params like this:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,email) VALUES (:user, :password, :email) ";
    //now lets update what :user should be
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $_POST['password'],
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    );

    //Now let's make run the query:
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        print_r($ex);
    }
```

Now do any errors occur? does your query run properly? Please provide more information to allow us to better help you.

---

**Sidenote**

Also turn on error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To help debug this issue.